# How to switch back and logout of masquerade user back to admin?

Tags: 7

I've setup masquerade module and switched to a regular user, but my switch back to admin block doesn't show up in the main theme and the user has no access to the admin theme. Is there a link I can use to switch myself back to admin?

Comment: The purpose of the module is exactly using a different account without logging in and out. It doesn't make sense to install the module, and then having to log out to be able to log in back as administrator.

Comment: Also, the project page clearly says _That person can switch back to their own user account at any time._ I take that as switching back in the same way the user switched to the other account (i.e. without entering the password).

Comment: It could be a way, but the OP didn't ask how to log in / log out. It would be like telling somebody who doesn't find how to stop an household appliance to switch off the electricity in the home/apartment. Indeed, the appliance would stop, but that is not the supposed way to stop the appliance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the module code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/masquerade/tree/masquerade.module), I notice the module defines a block with links for the masquerading operations. If that block is visible for the user account to which you switched, you should see a link to go back to your original account.

This is the code used from the module to show the block.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function masquerade_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'masquerade':
      if (isset($_SESSION['masquerading']) || (user_access('masquerade as user') || user_access('masquerade as admin'))) {
        $block['subject'] = t('Masquerade');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('masquerade_block_1');
      }
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Masquerade block form.
 */
function masquerade_block_1() {
  global $user;
  $quick_switch_links = array();
  $markup_value = '';
  if (isset($_SESSION['masquerading'])) {
    $quick_switch_links[] = l(t('Switch back'), 'masquerade/unswitch', array('query' => array('token' => drupal_get_token('masquerade/unswitch'))));
    if ($user->uid > 0) {
      $markup_value = t('You are masquerading as <a href="@user-url">%masq_as</a>.', array('@user-url' => url('user/' . $user->uid), '%masq_as' => $user->name));
    }
    else {
      $markup_value = t('You are masquerading as %anonymous.', array('%anonymous' => variable_get('anonymous', t('Anonymous'))));
    }
  }
  else {
    $quick_switches = variable_get('masquerade_quick_switches', array());

    // Add in user-specific switches, and prevent duplicates.
    $user_switches = db_query("SELECT uid_to FROM {masquerade_users} WHERE uid_from = :uid_from", array(':uid_from' => $user->uid))->fetchCol();
    $masquerade_switches = array_unique(array_merge($quick_switches, $user_switches));

    foreach ($masquerade_switches as $switch_user) {
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user']->uid) || $switch_user != $_SESSION['user']->uid) {
        $account = user_load($switch_user);
        if (isset($account->uid)) {
          $switch_link = 'masquerade/switch/' . $account->uid;
          if ($account->uid) {
            $quick_switch_links[] = l($account->name, $switch_link, array('query' => array('token' => drupal_get_token($switch_link))));
          }
          if ($switch_user == 0) {
            $account->name = variable_get('anonymous', t('Anonymous'));
            $quick_switch_links[] = l($account->name, $switch_link, array('query' => array('token' => drupal_get_token($switch_link))));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (masquerade_menu_access('autocomplete')) {
      $markup_value .= t('Enter the username to masquerade as.');
      $form['masquerade_user_field'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '18',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'masquerade/autocomplete',
        '#required' => TRUE,
      );
      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Go'),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );
    }

  }
  if ($quick_switch_links) {
    $markup_value .= '<div id="quick_switch_links">' . t('Quick switches:') . theme('item_list', array('items' => $quick_switch_links)) . '</div>';
  }
  $form['masquerade_desc'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="form-item"><div class="description">',
    '#markup' => $markup_value,
    '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Reading it, I see the same block shows you a *Switch back* link in the case you are masquerading as another user.
Assuming the block is enabled for all the roles in the site, and it is assigned to a region the currently-set theme uses, one of the reasons for the *Switch back* link not appearing could be an issue with the user session; in that case `isset($_SESSION['masquerading'])` could return `FALSE`.

There is also a bug report about switching back: [masquerade/unswitch throws a no acccess error](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156341). In that issue is clearly stated you need to use the block to switch back; it also seems there are some issues when the clear URLs aren't enabled.

Comment: There is no contradiction and no bug. A block can be not-enabled for all the roles: It's enough the block is show just for the users having a specific permission that was not assigned to every role. Do you see a bug, if not all users see the admin pages?